# Efficient way to delete ~3Billion records from a SQL Table containing 12Billion records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is how the table is structured :

```
Table A
{
    Id1 uniqueidentifier,
    Id2 nvarchar,
    Date datetime,
    Details nvarchar,
    Id3 uniqueidentifier
}
Clustered Index on {Id1 ASC, Details ASC, Date ASC}
Non-Clustered Index on {Date ASC}
No Foreign Key
```

All data has to be deleted which are of Feb [Currently the table has data from Feb-May]
The volume of data per day is `~100Million records` and total data till date stands to be `~12Billion Records`

As we recently created partitions, we only have partitions starting **May**, and `all data from Feb to April are in the same partition.`

It is a highly transactional table and we are hoping of the best way to do it without downtime.

Comment: I would suggest that you wait until July and then delete the Feb-April partition all at once.

Comment: We only have ~600GB of free space, and ~10days until the performance of the server degrades, so that might not be a feasible option for me.

Comment: There's a simple calculation - how much will it cost to have some downtime and spend a bunch of engineer time vs how much would a couple of extra disks cost for storage.

Comment: If the historical data are read-only, you could create a staging table partitioned by month, copy March and April data. Then truncate the target partition, split into monthly boundaries, and switch the staging table back in. You can then just just truncate and merge going forward to purge old data. Switch will require a brief schema modification lock.

Comment: @DavidG we currently are using SQL Managed Instances on Azure with Business Critical Service Tier and 4096GB storage. I can check what it takes to add in extra storage.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a batched delete code I've used over the years.  It allows for you to set batch size, run times (overnight period enforcement), etc.  It will also display the overall progress in the messages in SSMS.  Deleting in batches reduces overall performance impact and requires no downtime.  I've run this code on highly transactional servers during production hours without any impact.  Just make sure to keep the batch size under 5000 to prevent locking.

You may need to adjust some of the parameters based on your environment and server capabilities.  You'd obviously need to update this for your particular table name (instead of `SOMETABLE` below) as well as any other things specific to you, including adjusting the `WHERE` clause for your particular conditions.

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;
DECLARE @batchSize INT           = 4000,       -- keep under 5000 to prevent locking
        @waitInterval VARCHAR(8) = '00:00:10', -- wait interval between deletes
        @useWaitInterval BIT     = 1,          -- turn off/on wait between deletes
        @endTime VARCHAR(8)      = '08:00:00', -- 8AM
        @stopAtMaxTime BIT       = 1,          -- enforce stop time
        @iteration INT           = 0,          -- leave at 0
        @totalRows INT           = 0,          -- leave at 0
        @msg VARCHAR(500)

WHILE @batchSize > 0
BEGIN
    -- if @stopAtMaxTime = 1, stop whole job at set time...
    IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) >= @endTime AND @stopAtMaxTime = 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    DELETE TOP(@batchSize)
    FROM SOMETABLE
    WHERE 1 = 2

    SET @batchSize = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @iteration = @iteration + 1
    SET @totalRows = @totalRows + @batchSize 
    SET @msg = 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@iteration AS VARCHAR) + ' Total deletes:' + CAST(@totalRows AS VARCHAR)
    RAISERROR (@msg , 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    IF @useWaitInterval = 1
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY @waitInterval 
    END
END
```

Comment: It would be increasing the transactional log size also I believe. I had started this approach with batch size of 2000 but considering the rate, it would have taken weeks to cleanup 3Billion, so dropped the idea.

Comment: Yes, both of these things need to be taken into account with that volume of data.